# label not displaying in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6

I am using Xcode 5. I implemented a tableview and inserted 2 labels and two buttons in it. Its showing correctly in iOS 7, but only one label is shown in iOS6.

[image: iOS6][image: iOS7]

Thanks in advance

I used custom cell

```
UILabel *storeLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:0];
storeLabel.text=[_websites objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UILabel *priceLabel=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
priceLabel.text=[_prices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIButton * accessoryBtn=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
[accessoryBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryBtnClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIButton * shareBtn=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
 [shareBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(shareBtnClicked:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

[image: custom cell]

Comment: Seems like the UILabel 1 is covered on label 2. Check the label 1 frame

Comment: Show some code that how you add these labels.

Comment: Can you share your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: are you using custom cell for displaying cell data

Comment: give background color to each label and see if its  getting overlapped.